# Multiple rosbridge_websocket nodes

Tags: ros, rosbridge, multiple, roslibjs, websocket

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to run two rosbridge_websocket nodes - the only difference would be their names. What's the easiest way to do that? I was thinking that I could create my own ROS package based on the rosbridge_server package and modify the contents of the .launch file to assign appropriate node names. I'm not sure how to do this though or whether this is the right approach. Any help greatly appricated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249143/multiple-rosbridge_websocket-nodes/) by [Leonid](https://answers.ros.org/users/26807/leonid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2016-11-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to reuse `launch/rosbridge_websocket.launch`, then you could probably get away with pushing both instances into their own namespaces.

I haven't tried it, but something like:

```
<launch>
  <include ns="bridge0" file="$(find rosbridge_server)/launch/rosbridge_websocket.launch">
    <!-- use default port -->
    <arg name="port" value="9090" />
  </include>
  <include ns="bridge1" file="$(find rosbridge_server)/launch/rosbridge_websocket.launch">
    <!-- use other port -->
    <arg name="port" value="9091" />
  </include>
</launch>
```

You can override any of the `arg`s in `rosbridge_websocket.launch` in the same way.

Note that this will prefix all topics, services and actions that the `rosbridge_websocket` node creates/offers with the value in the `ns` attribute of the `include` tag.

If you want to avoid using namespaces, you could just copy `rosbridge_websocket.launch` to a package of your own (in your workspace), and copy the relative entries while making sure to change the `name` attribute of the `node` tag that starts `rosbridge_websocket`. But note that this will not work if `rosbridge_websocket` creates any *global* topics, services or actions, as they will then clash with each other.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1